# Volusion form not sending email

Tags: asp.net, forms, post, asp-classic, volusion

I am new here and not sure if I am post this correctly. I have created a custom form for my site and when submitted it does not send an email to the email specified. I have searched and tried multiple things to try and get it to work.

My form is:

```
<form name="myForm" action="subform.asp" onSubmit="return validateForm();" method="post">
First Name:<input type="text" size="30" name="fname" maxlength="5"><br>
Last name:<input type="text" size="30" name="lname" maxlength="30"><br>
Email:<input type="text" size="30" name="email" maxlength="30"><br>
Comments:<textarea rows="2" cols="22" name="comments"></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

My subform.asp:

```
<% 
Option Explicit
Dim referer
Dim siteurl
Dim email_from
Dim email_to
Dim strMsg
Dim vsmtpKey

referer = Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_REFERER")
siteurl = "www.mysite.com"
email_from = "email@mysite.com"
email_to = "email@mysite.com"
vsmtpKey = "my key"


strMsg = "First Name : " & request.form("fname") & "<br>" 
strMsg = "Last Name : " & request.form("lname") & "<br>" 
strMsg = "Email : " & request.form("email") & "<br>" 
strMsg = "Comments : " & request.form("comments") & "<br>" 

if InStr(referer, siteurl ) > 0 Then

    Dim HTTPRequest
    Set HTTPRequest = CreateObject("WinHTTP.WinHTTPRequest.5.1")
    HTTPRequest.Open "POST", "http://" & Request.ServerVariables("LOCAL_ADDR") & "subform.asp", False
    HTTPRequest.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    HTTPRequest.SetRequestHeader "Host", Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_NAME")
    HTTPRequest.Send _
        "VsmtpKey=" & vsmtpKey &_
        "&Subject=" & Server.URLEncode("Mailing List Submission") &_
        "&FromEmailAddress=" & email_from &_
        "&ToEmailAddress=" & email_to &_
        "&Body_HTML=" &  Server.URLEncode(strMsg)

    response.write(HTTPRequest.ResponseText)
    Set HTTPRequest = Nothing
End If

%>
```

Comment: Did you ever determine if ASP mail works on Volusion or not?

Answer (score 0):

If the CDO.Message is available on your server, this might be a simpler option?

```
<%
Set myMail=CreateObject("CDO.Message")
myMail.Subject="Sending email with CDO"
myMail.From="mymail@mydomain.com"
myMail.To="someone@somedomain.com"
myMail.TextBody="This is a message."
myMail.Send
set myMail=nothing
%>
```

Code from: [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_send_email.asp)

I suggest this as everything looks ok with your code as far as setting the email up goes, but I've never seen the "WinHTTP.WinHTTPRequest.5.1" class used to send mail with classic asp.

If you have to use the WinHTTP method, I guess you've checked the objects are being created successfully, and all the data you expect is present? Failing that, could it be a server / network issue blocking the mail from being sent?

Answer (score 0):

```
HTTPRequest.Open "POST", "http://" & Request.ServerVariables("LOCAL_ADDR") & "subform.asp", False
```

Try change "subform.asp" to "/vsmtp.asp", False

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this too.  I tried to do similar as you and ended up getting it to work with this...(I also had to download the file VSMTP_CLASS.asp and FTP it to the folder /vspfiles -- which is where the file resides with the code below):

```
emailer.asp test
<!--#include file="VSMTP_CLASS.asp"-->
<% 
Dim mailer 
Set mailer = new vsmtp 
mailer.VsmtpKey = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
mailer.EmailSubject = "Test Subject" 
mailer.EmailFrom = "XXXX@ZZZZZZ.com" 
mailer.EmailTo = "me@mydomainXXXX.com" 
mailer.TextBody = "Hello World!" 
mailer.HTMLBody = "Hello World" 
mailer.Send() 


%>
```

The VSTMP file is here for downloading...
https://store.volusion.com/v/vspfiles/manual/kb/VSMTP_CLASS.zip

Comment: Is there any volusion API for getting products information through JQuery?

Comment: $('#<class_name>').load("/v/vspfiles/getProductInfo.asp?productId="+global_Current_ProductCode);

And then in the getProductInfo.asp file, you can call the Volusion API....

productId= Request.QueryString("productId")
url =       "http://www.YOUR_SITE.com/net/WebService.aspx?Login=XXXXX@url =       "http://www.YOUR_SITE.com/net/WebService.aspx?Login=XXXXX@YOUR_SITE&EncryptedPassword=XXXXE&EDI_Name=Generic\Products&SELECT_Columns=pe.ProductPrice&WHERE_Column=p.ProductCode&WHERE_Value="

Comment: oXMLHttp.open "POST", url&productId, False
 oXMLHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8"
 oXMLHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Action", "Volusion_API"
 oXMLHttp.setTimeouts 100000, 100000, 600000, 9999999
 Server.ScriptTimeout = 10800
 ' Send the Xml
 oXMLHttp.send ""
 getApiXml = oXMLHttp.responseText
set xmlDoc = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument")
xmlDoc.loadXML (getApiXml )
productprice = xmlDoc.selectSingleNode("//ProductPrice").text